# JWT Token That Never Expires For A Specific Route Group

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, jwt

I have a laravel web application.  Several 3rd parties connect to the APIs on my server, the website uses those same APIs and so does my mobile app.  Now for the website I am fine with the token expiring after a certain time preferably 1 hour.  However for my mobile app I do not want the token to expire at all.

I know with [Tymon/JWTAuth](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth) I can do this in the config file or my .env file but this applies to the entire app, how do I set specific token expiration lengths for each route group I have?